# Laravel Resource controller edit function not working

Tags: php, laravel

When i go to my edit page and want to edit a post out of my blog and make changes it changes but not in the post with that id it just makes a new post with another id

Code:

edit function:

```
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param Integer $id
     * @return Response
     */

    public function edit($id)
    {
        return view('/blog/edit')->with(['blog' => Blog::findOrFail($id)]);
    }
```

edit form:

```
<form action="/blog" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="formGroupExampleInput"></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" name="titel"
                               placeholder="Title" value="{{ $blog->titel }}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Lead</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="lead" placeholder="Blog lead">{{ $blog->lead }}</textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Another label</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="text" placeholder="Blog text">{{ $blog->text }}</textarea>
                    </div>
                    <input type="file" id="real-file" name="bestand" >
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
```

thank you for your time

Comment: Please show us the relevant routes and also the method you use to save the blog.

Comment: Also, Laravel adheres to REST verbs so updates need to be sent via `PUT`. HTML forms don't support `PUT` so you have to spoof it. Read more here - https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html and also https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#method-spoofing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to pass id of that resource you are editing

```
<form action="/blog/{{ $blog->id }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> // <----this line needs id of the resource
    @csrf
    {{method_field('PUT')}} //<----you have to add method PUT
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="formGroupExampleInput"></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" name="titel"
               placeholder="Title" value="{{ $blog->titel }}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Lead</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="lead" placeholder="Blog lead">{{ $blog->lead }}</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Another label</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="text" placeholder="Blog text">{{ $blog->text }}</textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="file" id="real-file" name="bestand" >
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```